# Unable to display data fetched from real-time database (firebase) in my RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm new to the concepts of RecyclerView and Firebase; I'm working on this chat app that takes input from the user (message) and takes the DisplayName(Google sign in, so the Username) and stores it to the realtime database of the Firebase. The storing of the "mAuthor" and "mMessage" is working fine, the problem arises when I'm trying to retrieve the data and display it in the recyclerView. There's no crash error as per the Logcat, however, there's nothing getting displayed on my chat app screen (in the recyclerView).

The dependencies of firebase and recyclerView have been carefully added.

Here's my activity class:

```
     private String mDisplayName;
     private EditText mMessage;
     private ImageView mSendButton;
     private RecyclerView mRecycler;
     private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
     private MyAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    mMessage=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageInput);
    mSendButton=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    setupDisplayName();

    mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRecycler=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chat_recycler_view);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mMessage.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            sendMessage();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });



}

private void setupDisplayName(){
    Intent mIntent= getIntent();
    String option= mIntent.getStringExtra("Options");

    if(option.equals("normal")){
        SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences(RegisterActivity.CHAT_PREFS,0);
        mDisplayName=prefs.getString(RegisterActivity.DISPLAY_NAME_KEY,null);
        Log.d("Google","Shared prefs: DisplayName:"+mDisplayName);
    }

    else if(option.equals("google")){
        SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.CHAT_PREFS,0);
        mDisplayName=prefs.getString(MainActivity.DISPLAY_NAME_KEY,null);
        Log.d("Google","Shared prefs: DisplayName:"+mDisplayName);

    }
if(mDisplayName==null)
            mDisplayName="Anonymous";

}

private void sendMessage() {

    String input= mMessage.getText().toString();
    if(!input.equals("")){
        Log.d("Google","I sent something");
        InstantMessage mObject= new InstantMessage(mDisplayName, input);
        mDatabaseReference.child("messages").push().setValue(mObject);
        mMessage.setText("");
    }
}

    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAdapter= new MyAdapter(mDatabaseReference, mDisplayName);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mAdapter.CleanUp();
}
```

Here's my Model class:

```
    public class InstantMessage {

private String mAuthor;
private String mMessage;

public InstantMessage(String mAuthor, String mMessage) {
    this.mAuthor = mAuthor;
    this.mMessage = mMessage;
}

public InstantMessage() {
}

public String getmAuthor() {
    return mAuthor;
}

public void setmAuthor(String mAuthor) {
    this.mAuthor = mAuthor;
}

public void setmMessage(String mMessage) {
    this.mMessage = mMessage;
}

public String getmMessage() {
    return mMessage;
}
```

}

Here's my Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private DatabaseReference mReference;
private String mDisplayName;
private List<InstantMessage> mList;
private ChildEventListener mListener= new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        InstantMessage msg= dataSnapshot.getValue(InstantMessage.class);
        mList.add(msg);
        Log.d("Google","Datasnapshot added:"+dataSnapshot.toString());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};

public MyAdapter( DatabaseReference mReference, String mDisplayName) {
    this.mReference = mReference.child("messages");
    mReference.addChildEventListener(mListener);
    this.mDisplayName = mDisplayName;
    mList= new ArrayList<>();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_row, parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mAuthorName.setText(mList.get(position).getmAuthor());
    holder.mText.setText(mList.get(position).getmMessage());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d("Google","Item count:"+mList.size());
    return mList.size();
}

public void CleanUp(){
    mReference.removeEventListener(mListener);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mAuthorName;
    TextView mText;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mAuthorName=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Chatauthor);
        mText= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Chatmessage);


    }
}
```

}

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. In the log statement of onChildAdded method, the datasnapshot.toString() returns legit values. However, the Log.d("Google","Item Count:"+mList.size()) returns ItemCount: 1 everytime

PS: Here's the data that is being sent to the firebase: https://imageshack.com/a/img922/1458/HoOWxO.png

My activity_chat_row.xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Chatauthor"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:textColor="#3CB371"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Author"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Chatmessage"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, 
you try to display all chat message after application chat message screen load or update chat screen after anyone sends the message or change message.database.

Comment: you can use this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888425/6238866.

Comment: @MayurPatel yeah I can but I want to know why my posted code isn't working

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur I tried that but still there's nothing displayed

Comment: can you show you database structure?

Comment: try to make log of `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();` inside `onChildAdded`

Comment: @VadimEksler I added the url to the screencap I took of the database structure at the end of the post

Comment: @PratyushSahu you are set your MyAdapter constructor in list after the assigning addChildEventListener. Pls try assign list first and then set addChildEventListener to your firebase reference.

Comment: @PratyushSahu remove notifyDataSetChanged(); from onChildAdded method because it will notify all the list every time while data will change.

Comment: @PratyushSahu share your activity_chat_row.xml

Comment: @VadimEksler dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() returned the value "33", same as the number of messages in the database

Comment: @MayurPatel did both of the things you told me to, nothing changed

Comment: try to make `mList= new ArrayList<>();` in first line of constructor before you add your mListener.

Comment: @MayurPatel added the xml code to the end of the post

Comment: @VadimEksler did that, nothing changed

Comment: @PratyushSahu change your LinearLayout height with wrap_content.

Comment: please check whether  the  onChildAdded event is firing or not ?

Comment: @MayurPatel nothing happened on doing that

Comment: @HovanesMosoyan it is firing as the Log statement in the onChildAdded method returns a certain value

Comment: Fixed it, changed the "mReference.addChildEventListener(mListener)" in the MyAdapter constructor to "this.mReference.addChildEventListener(mListener)", thank you

Comment: Good Luck to all )