# Retrieve Firebase data to ListView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building an Android app and using Firebase as its backend database, however i'm having difficulties to retrieve the data and display them in a `ListView`. I tried few codes but the app is crashing as soon as i display the list activity.

Below is a screenshot of my database and also my code and the error I get when I try to run:

[Firebase Databse Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/793lB.png)

[image]

```
public class ClientLIstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button clientSelect;
private ListView clientlistView;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_list);


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    clientlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Clients");

    clientlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientListView);
    clientSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectClient);

    clientSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
           list.add(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance, PID: 6602
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepg.zzb(Unknown Source:93)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepg.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                      at com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance.ClientLIstActivity$2.onChildAdded(ClientLIstActivity.java:53)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegg.zza(Unknown Source:71)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelk.zzcal(Unknown Source:2)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelq.run(Unknown Source:71)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: You may try this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888425/6238866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, just move the following line of code:

```
clientlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientListView);
```

right before this line:

```
clientlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You first need to instantiate the `ListView` object before actually using it.

Comment: I tried this but still getting an error but a different. Looks like it can't convert Hashmap to String from my Clients object class. I updated my error log can you check it?

Comment: The fact hat you get another error, it means that the initial error disappeared and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new problem which is basically another question that I cannot responde in a comment or using only the the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are using a wrong database reference but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: I don't know whether it fixed it or not because there's another error now, so as soon as that is fixed i'll accept it

Comment: @JakeQuinter Since the error for which you have asked the question is gone, it means that the problem is solved. Whith other words, this questions can be considered close. You might encounter from this moment, one or more other errors but it doesn't mean that this problem isn't solved. But ok, keep me posted.

Comment: @JakeQuinter You can also give me a link with the new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52168551/retrieve-firebase-data-and-display-in-listview-in-android-studio

Link to the new question

Comment: @JakeQuinter Just answered. Please also make sure to solve the problem regarding the name of your variables, ok?

Answer (score 1):

You missed create the instance of your listview
**clientListView = findViewById(R.id.your_listView_id);**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_list);

    clientListView = findViewById(R.id.your_listView_id);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    clientlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Clients");
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to initialize the clientlistView and the you have to set the listview to the adapter,

In your programm you are setting the adapter view without initializing the clientlistview

you need to write your code like this

```
clientListView = findViewById(R.id.your_listView_id);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
clientlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
```